# Inserting returns from dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, quantmod

I´m trying to insert a column in a dataframe named Reference with returns of stocks obtained from another dataframe called Quotes.

```
Quotes <- data.frame (Ticker = c("Petr4","Petr4","Petr4","Abev3","Abev3","Petr4","Petr4","Abev3","Abev3","Abev3" ), 
                  Close = c(15.80,15.55,15.90,18.52,19.57,16.25,16.50,19.20,19.18,19.7))

Reference <- aggregate(cbind(Close) ~ Ticker, data = (Quotes), FUN = last)
```

This is how the inserted column would like (Last N Days return):

```
Reference$Return <- c(0.044303797,0.063714903)
```

I´m using Quantmod FUN Last to get the last quote, any other idea?

Comment: Could you be more specific about how is the c(0.044303797,0.063714903) calculated from the given dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

The value on Reference is divided by the lagged value on Quote. In the first case 16.50 ( Last value of Petr4 divided by its lagged (-5)value of 15.8 minus 1.